# managed object context is a transactional log?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager

I heard somewhere that `NSManagedObjectContext` is a transactional log, so context stores operations with date when they were performed.

Is it right? Am I able to get back this log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSManagedObjectContext has

- insertedObjects
- updatedObjects
- deletedObjects

properties, that contains the aggregated changes, but it has more detailed info too, if `undoManager` is enabled. Then a transaction log is available, and can `undo` / `redo` / `reset` changes in order as changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

No, conceptually it's more like a diff against its parent, whether that's a persistent store or a parent context. NSUndoManager may help your specific situation, though I've never used it myself.